# Save output of jsonb_each in a materialized view

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Table ‘t’ in PG 12-

```
Id int

Col1 character varying

Data_col jsonb
```

Data_col is something like below:

{key1:value 1, key2: value 2, key3: value 3....}

I can get the key & values in tow form using below select

```
Select t.id, t.col1, x.key, x.value
From t, jsonb_each_text(t.data_col) x
```

I would like yo know if there is a way to store the output of above select into a materialized view?
I tried-

```
Create materialized view t_mv
As
Select t.id, t.col1, x.key, x.value
From t, jsonb_each_text(t.data_col) x;
```

But I get an error

```
error cannot call jsonb_each on a non-object
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the values in `t.data_col` must be an array or a scalar:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text('"scalar"'::jsonb);
ERROR:  cannot call jsonb_each_text on a non-object

SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text('[1,2,3]'::jsonb);
ERROR:  cannot call jsonb_each_text on a non-object
```

To find the problematic rows you can use a query like

```
SELECT id FROM t WHERE jsonb_typeof(data_col) <> 'object';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt should work.  There is a mismatch in column name in your query though.  The query uses col2 but the table is defined with col1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. That was a typo, I’ve corrected it.